# Fetching all changes made by a user in hibernate envers

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-envers, audit-logging

In hibernate envers, I can get all changes made to an entity by using the following piece of code:

```
AuditQuery aq = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges(DummyEntity.class, false);
```

But is there a way to get all the changes made by a particular user for all entities?

I'm using the following entity to store revision info:

```
@RevisionEntity(UserRevisionListener.class)
@Entity(name = "env_audit_envers_info")
public class AuditEnversInfo extends DefaultRevisionEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7604731515258123883L;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}
```

And entries to this model will be added on every change using the following listener:

```
public class UserRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        AuditEnversInfo auditEnversInfo = (AuditEnversInfo) revisionEntity;
        Optional<Authentication> auth = Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        String username = auth.isPresent() ? auth.get().getName() : "anonymoususer@email.com";
        auditEnversInfo.setUserId(username);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AuditEntity#revisionProperty` method is what you're looking for:

```
List results = auditReader.createQuery()
  .forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges( DummyEntity.class, false )
  .add( AuditEntity.revisionProperty( "userId" ).eq( userId ) )
  .getResultList();
```

The `#revisionProperty` methods were added to allow users who extend or use custom revision entity instances in their audit domain model to be able to add restrictions / projections or to be able to sort the results based on fields on that model.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)